# Plotly.js with Angular how to automatically resize choropleth

Tags: javascript, angular, responsive, choropleth, plotly.js

I'm trying to use Plotly.js with Angular 6 to display a choropleth that automatically resize and is responsive. I don't want to set static width or height. How should I make the choropleth automatically fit a div?

It seems like the plot is expanding to the full size but not the map itself.

[image: This is how it looks right now]

I tried to use Plotly.restyle function without any success, here's the current code:

> ```
>   @ViewChild('chart') el: ElementRef;
>   @HostListener('window:resize')
>   onResize() {
>     if (this.element) {
>       Plotly.Plots.resize(this.element);
>     }
>   }
> ```

Here's the code for initializing the choropleth:

> ```
>   private plot() {
>     this.element = this.el.nativeElement;
>     Plotly.plot(this.element, this.data, this.style, this.config);
>     Plotly.Plots.resize(this.element);
>   }
>
>   private get style(): any {
>     return {
>       autosize: true,
>       title: this.title,
>       geo: {
>         showframe: false,
>         showcoastlines: true,
>         projection: {
>           type: 'mercator'
>         }
>       }
>     };
>   }
>
>   private get data(): any {
>     const countries = this.markers.map(marker => marker.country);
>     return [
>       {
>         type: 'choropleth',
>         locations: countries,
>         z: this.markers.map(marker => marker.value),
>         text: countries,
>         autocolorscale: false,
>         reversescale: true,
>
>         marker: {
>           line: {
>             color: 'rgb(255,255,255)',
>             width: 0.3
>           }
>         },
>         showscale: false
>       }
>     ];
>   }
> ```

Can somebody please give me some insight on this?